# Why would PivotTable.EnableFieldList take away conditional formatting?

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table, conditional-formatting

this seems like a strange question and I hope there is a simple explanation like I've overlooked something... but what?

I have some code which happily creates a pivot table and then applies conditional formatting to it.  I must admit, the conditional formatting bit is not the most elegant as I just copied it from a recorded macro, but it does the job:

```
Range("I:I").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=VALUE(TEXT(OFFSET(I1,0,-1),""#,###""))>0"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
        .TintAndShade = 0.599963377788629
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

Today, I decided to add something to the code, to disable some pivot table functionality - I want to prevent users from accessing the Field List.  I have added the below, which takes place right after the conditional formatting section:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
  .EnableFieldList = False
End With
```

Suddenly, when I run it with the new addition, the conditional formatting is lost!  Not a coloured cell in sight.  It does successfully disable the field list, so at least there's that.  Any ideas at all?

Comment: The problem with applying CF like that is that it gets overwritten when the pivot table refreshes. You should be adding the CF rules to specific pivot table fields if possible.

Comment: Thanks, Rory.  This specific pivot table isn't supposed to refresh - the worksheet and pivot get created from scratch every time the code is run - but is it possible that it's being refreshed without my having told it to?  (I know I haven't pasted the full code here, but I guess my question is, are there functions which imply a refresh even if it's not explicitly stated?)

Comment: Yes it looks like disabling the field list causes a refresh of the table, which removes the CF from that part of the column.

Comment: Interesting; that's useful to bear in mind.  I've left it as is for now, but if/when I have time I will have a go at that - found a thread here which seems to explain how (note to self!): http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=190211

Answer (score 0):

If you apply the conditional formatting after disabling the field list, it'll work

Comment: Thanks, Sam - just tried that, but weirdly, it doesn't then disable the field list.  It seems like Excel will only allow one or the other, whichever comes first in the code.  So strange!

Comment: What Excel version do you have? It works in my Excel 2016

Comment: I'm using Excel 2013.